# React - fetch some data before ssr and fetch some data on client side

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, client-side

I have an app written in reactjs running on firebase which is completely rendered on client side. The problem is Search engines and SEO.

App's pages are dynamically rendered based on variables in url path.

I am thinking to enable SSR - according to some articles I need to use express server or nextjs server. Also thinking that some data can be loaded from external api before server rendering and some data can be loaded on client side. Is this possible?

Is this good approach? How would you solve this problem without using third party components such as prerender.io?

App was created by using `npx create-react-app my-app`

Thanks for advices.

Comment: Next.js is helpful but you'll need to migrate from CRA to use it (here is a lot of examples that cover your cases: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples). If you don't want to use it you can implement SSR server by yourself (here is good example: https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReactSSRCasts).

Comment: I suggest you to inspect what is causing the issues with SEO in the first place. I had some good experiences with client-side rendered apps that had no problems being indexed and ranked by Google Search. Going the SSR route - while providing a number of benefits - is also going to make your whole setup much more complex and it will expose you to some problems you don't currently face.